# Django is not rendering my static file (css, images, etc)

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I am able to view my site (html)in the browser but none of my mark-up is working.  I have checked my stylesheet links for types, settings.py, but I am at a lost.
When I run my site I am getting the below responses in my terminal.

```
[10/Nov/2022 20:46:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 168
[10/Nov/2022 20:46:23] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1795
[10/Nov/2022 20:46:23] "GET /static/images/6%2Bcart.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1810`
```

Here is code from my settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/' 
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

Example of my css link in my html page

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
```

I have tried going over everything possible but cannot locate the issue,  any and all feedback would be greatly appreciated.
I am not allowed to post images yet so unfortunately, I could not include.

I have re-coded, deleted and remade static folder, scoured the internet with no luck yet.

Comment: show folder structure please and urls.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this static file configuration, this is work well for me.

In settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles') # for deployment
```

And add in urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [

    """
    -----
    -----
    """
 ]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL , document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

If it still doesn't work, you can add below code in your urlpatterns to force django to serve static files.

```
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root':settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
```

Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static './css/main.css' %}">
```